VBScript and loadXML: Parsing XML doesn't return expected results
I need help and hope I will get it here.
My task is to automize the process of loading exchange rate list from the web to our database.
In Task Scheduler I have created a daily task which downloads the xml file with the exchange rate list.
I have tried to parse the file with two options I've found on the web but no one worked as expected.
The first scenario code:
Dim sXpath
Dim node
Dim ExDate, ExCurrency, ExRate

Dim oXml, b, aNodes, i, lastNode

Set oXml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
oXml.async = false   ' Set synchronize load file
b = oXml.load("C:\Tecajnica\dtecbs.xml")   ' Connect/load XML file

Set aNodes = oXml.getElementsByTagName("tecaj")   ' The array of tags
lastNode = aNodes.length - 1   ' The total number of tags

For i = 0 To lastNode
    sXPath = "//tecajnica[@datum]"
    Set node = aNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode(sXPath)
    ExDate = node.getAttribute("datum")

    sXPath = "//tecajnica/tecaj[@oznaka]"
    Set node = aNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode(sXPath)
    ExCurrency = node.getAttribute("oznaka")

    sXPath = "//tecajnica/tecaj"
    Set node = aNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode(sXPath)
    ExRate = node.text

    MsgBox "Counter: " & i & " Date: " & ExDate & " Currency: " & ExCurrency & " Exchange Rate: " & ExRate
Next

This code loops through all currencies but it always returns data for first currency:
Counter: 0 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
Counter: 1 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
Counter: 2 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
Counter: 3 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
Counter: 4 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
Counter: 5 Date: 2024-09-27 Currency: USD Exchange Rate: 1.1158
The second scenario code:
Dim xmlDoc, ExDates, ExCurrencies
Dim plot, ExDate, ExCurrency, ExRate

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("C:\\Tecajnica\\dtecbs.xml")

plot = "No value"

For Each ExDates In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//tecajnica")
    ExDate = ExDates.getAttribute("datum")
    For Each ExCurrencies In ExDates.SelectNodes("//tecaj")
        ExCurrency = ExCurrencies.getAttribute("oznaka")
        ExRate = ExCurrencies.text
        MsgBox "Datum: " & ExDate & " Valuta: " & ExCurrency & " Tečaj: " & ExRate
    Next
Next

This code doesn't even enter into loop. However it works if I remove node <DtecBS> from XML.
Please help me correct the first or second code to make it work.
Here is an example of xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DtecBS xmlns="http://www.bsi.si" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bsi.si http://www.bsi.si/_data/tecajnice/DTecBS.xsd">
<tecajnica datum="2024-09-27">
    <tecaj oznaka="USD" sifra="840">1.1158</tecaj>
    <tecaj oznaka="JPY" sifra="392">159.63</tecaj>
    <tecaj oznaka="BGN" sifra="975">1.9558</tecaj>
    <tecaj oznaka="CZK" sifra="203">25.158</tecaj>
    <tecaj oznaka="PLN" sifra="985">4.2738</tecaj>
    <tecaj oznaka="RON" sifra="946">4.9764</tecaj>
</tecajnica>
</DtecBS>


This question is similar to: VBScript, MSXML and Namespaces. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Issue with XML / SelectNodes using ASP VBScript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are plenty of existing questions that deal with issues loading and parsing XML in VBScript, please try searching first before posting as this is not a new topic and has been discussed many times before.

Note the 2 suggested questions above (1, 2) are better duplicate targets for the issue here, which is about namespacing.

Your XML has a default namespace. It means that every single XML element is bound to it.
You need to declare that default namespace in the code with a prefix, and use it while referring to the XML elements in the XPath expressions.
VBSCRIPT
...
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='http://www.bsi.si'"

For Each ExDates In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//ns:tecajnica")
    ExDate = ExDates.getAttribute("datum")
    For Each ExCurrencies In ExDates.SelectNodes("//ns:tecaj")
        ExCurrency = ExCurrencies.getAttribute("oznaka")
        ExRate = ExCurrencies.text
        MsgBox "Datum: " & ExDate & " Valuta: " & ExCurrency & " Tečaj: " & ExRate
    Next
Next


Correct answer, but like I’ve mentioned in the comments, nothing new that hasn’t been covered multiple times over the years.

@user692942, I completely concur. Unfortunately, XML namespaces puzzle so many people.

@YitzhakKhabinsky thank you very much. I apologize for asking help for the issue it's been explained many times. Just want to point out that also people like me who are not professionals have sometimes to work with xml and if you answer with correction of code is much more clear then the explanation of theory behind. For us amateurs of course.

@MilaKotnik There in lies the problem "[so] is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers" (taken from the Tour). If the same answer is given over and over it dilutes the solution and makes it harder for programmers to find the answer they are looking for.

I apologize once again. Thank you for your time and effort. And I really appreciate your help. Now I'm not sure if I should delete my question.

No need to do that. Everything is fine
